# Ros compile error. Error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [16], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’

Tags: c++, ros

Hello I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am very new to Ros. I was using ros kinetic. I have switched to the Ros melodic version and I am getting a compilation error in my cpp file. Below you can see my code and error I will be very happy if you could help.
this is my code:

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <std_msgs/String.h>
    #include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
    #include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    /** Function Declarations **/
    bool moveToGoal(double xGoal, double yGoal, double yaw);
    void choose();
    
    //code*****
    
    
    
    void move(const std_msgs::String msg){
        cout << "move Function activated" << endl;
        //***code
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        ros::init(argc, argv, "map_navigation4");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
    
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe ("server_messages", 1, move);
    
        ros::spin();
        return 0;
    }
    
    bool moveToGoal(double xGoal, double yGoal, double yaw){
        //**code
    }
```

and this error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2xeO.png)

Comment: Why are you using `using namespace std;` and defining a function named `move`? See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This isn't the OP's problem but I landed here with the same error message. In my case the error was to declare the `ros::NodeHandle` `const`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you subscriber is not recognizing your **move** callback function. Below modification to your code should fix the issue-

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "map_navigation4");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("server_messages", 1, moveCB);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

And the callback function -

```
void moveCB(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)
{
     cout << "move Function activated" << endl;
     const char *a = msg->data.c_str();
     /**
     * Your Code
     */
}
```

Reference

1. [ROS code documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a317fe4c05919e0bf3fb5162ccb2f7c28)
2. [ROS Publisher and Subscriber Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Comment: Thank you for your attention and assistance. I tried editing it but the error could not be resolved. Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're saying. I am also pretty bad at using cpp. Could there be definitions about libraries that I need to change?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. When run `ros::spin()` it will start the subscriber thread `moveCB`. This function will start every time `server_messages` topic is updated.

Comment: Your callback function should be unique so that it recognizes that topic. Have tried change the name of your callback function?

Comment: thank you for your attention @VishnuprasadPrachandabhanu I've tried and didn't work. i think the problem is with ros version because the cod seamless for ros kinetic. I'm still searching. But I went back to ros kinetic to prevent my project from slowing down.